# Extending Existing Eclipse Editors

Tags: java, json, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Is this possible?

**Here is the problem I am trying to solve:**

I have 3 configuration files one .ini, one .config, and one .json

Then I have a bunch of SQL files that have sort-of a customized version of sql in them.

I need to do some syntax validation on these files, and I also added syntax highlighting.  In the performSave function I made a call to the validator.

It would be nice to have this update dynamically as you typed, but I couldn't figure that part out just yet.

My problem is this: most of these config files and sql files have our own special brand of syntax, but the JSON file is just a regular old json file so it seems silly to create my own editor and re implement syntax coloring for something so widely in use.  I was hoping that I could just extend a current existing editor already in eclipse then just add my hooks where I need them.

**Heres what I have done so far:**

I created some Eclipse plugins for work ing with these files.  Most notably I have created a .sql editor, a .config editor, and a .ini editor.  So for the most part I know how to create an editor and do my syntax coloring and problem marking etc.  I would just like to ride the coat tails of someone who has already created a JSON editor so that all I need to add is my validation calls.

If you have any insight into extending an existing editor that would be great.

Also any help with where to put my validator call to mark up files while they are being created except on a save would be awesome too.

-Best,
Jeff

Comment: You create your own editor with its definition in your plugin, but your editor class can extends the existing editor class, and your plugin defines the existing editor plugin as a dependency.

Comment: I installed the Eclipse Json Editor Plugin from the market place, then created a new json editor package. in my editors plug in.  I made the plugin a dependency, then I did :

`
import com.boothen.jsonedit.core.editors.*;

public class jsonEditor extends JsonPageEditor {
`
And I still get red squigglies.  Namely - "
Access restriction: The type 'JsonPageEditor' is not API (restriction on required library '/Applications/eclipse/plugins/jsonedit-core_0.9.7.jar') jsonEditor.java /com.myinfo.eclipseplugin.workflowmanager.editors/src/com/myinfo/eclipseplugin/workflowmanager/editors/jsonEditor"

Comment: I modified the access rules, and made every module of the jsonEdit plug in a dependency.  I no longer get the quibbles and I can extend the existing classes, but when I go to run test the class snow I get an error: 

"Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.boothen.jsonedit.core.editors.JsonTextEditor cannot be found by com.myinfo.eclipseplugin.workflowmanager.editors_1.0.0.qualifier"

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Xtext to get a feature rich editor (on the fly syntax correction, code completion etc..) rather than implementing from scratch ?

For JSON, the grammar fits in a few lines :
https://gist.github.com/nightscape/629651

Just build a "New->Xtext Project", then stick this grammar into it and run as "Generate Xtext artifacts", you'll get an extensible editor in no time.

There is a feature to add validation rules checked on the fly easily using Java or Xtend.